# Create a folder and write multiple files on a loop

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to write a number of files in node to a specific folder, but I am having some issues when creating the folder:

I got an `upload.js` file that recieves two files from the front end, then I am using an async for loop not to block the event loop, and I have a function that I run for each file it receives, this funtion checks if the folder exists and if not it creates it:

```
import Router from 'express'
import multer from 'multer'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { constants } from 'fs'
import { writeFile, mkdir, access } from 'fs/promises'

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
    await callback(array[i], i, array)
  }
}

router.put('/', upload.array('files', 5), async (req, res) => {
  const { files } = req

  const temporalFolder = `./tmp`

  const writeToFolder = async (name, file) => {
    try {
      await access(temporalFolder, constants.R_OK | constants.W_OK)
    } catch (error) {
      await mkdir(temporalFolder)
    } finally {
      await writeFile(resolve(temporalFolder, name), file)
    }
  }

  await asyncForEach(files, async (file) => { 
    const { originalname, buffer } = file
    writeToFolder(originalname, buffer)
  }

  res.end()
})

export default router
```

If the folder is already created I get no error and it works fine, but the first time when the folder does not exist I get this even thou all works:

```
[Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir './tmp'] {
   errno: -17,
   code: 'EEXIST',
   syscall: 'mkdir',
   path: './tmp'
}
```

Update: Thanks to Rajdeep Debnath I fixed it with this:

```
const writeToFolder = async (name, file) => {
  try {
    await access(temporalFolder, constants.R_OK | constants.W_OK)
  } catch (error) {
    await mkdir(temporalFolder, { recursive: true })
  } finally {
    await writeFile(resolve(temporalFolder, name), file)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer on why this happens, but I'd suggest to move the check if the targetfolder exists from within `writeToFolder` to be executed before the `asyncForEach`. There's no need to check the existance of the folder again for every file to be written...

Comment: The reson for this is that I am doing some validations before writing, so if the validation fails I dont want to create the folder in the first place

Comment: Is there any possibility that these validations are in the same block as `await access(...)` and one of them throws an error? Because if that's the case, it will go into the `catch` block and try to create the directory, even if `access` didn't throw an error ... Just add a `console.log(error)` right before `await mkdir(...)` to see, what error was thrown, to cause the `catch` to be executed

Comment: No, the validations are in the for loop, and only attempts to create the dir and write file if there are no errors

Comment: In regard to usage of `access`, could it be related to the `Race Condition` referred in that Func's documentation?

"Using fsPromises.access() to check for the accessibility of a file before calling fsPromises.open() is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not accessible."

ref: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_access_path_mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `fs.promises.mkdir()` when path is a directory that exists results in an error only when `recursive` is `false`. So you need to pass `{recursive:true}` as the second option

```
const writeToFolder = async (name, file) => {
  try {
    await mkdir(temporalFolder, {recursive:true})
    await writeFile(resolve(temporalFolder, name), file)
  } catch (error) {
```

Comment: Actually the `recursive: true` helped just not the way you are using in the example, I basically used the same example as the one above using `access`, ansd using `mkdir` with `recursive: true` and no errors now. I have edited the final solution and giving you the `Accepted answer`